Issues Installing LangChain: Missing Methods in langchain.chains
I've been trying to set up LangChain for a while now, but no matter how I install it (via pip or conda, using a virtual environment or not), I can't seem to access most of the methods within langchain.chains.
For instance, when I try to import:
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
from langchain.chains import create_retrieval_chain

None of these methods are available, and it's the same for other methods under langchain.chains.
I noticed that using very old versions of LangChain (<=0.0.2) lets me access some legacy methods, but this is not a viable long-term solution.
Current environment package versions:
python                            3.10.12
langchain                          0.3.2
langchain-core                     0.3.9
langchain-ollama                   0.2.0
langchain-text-splitters           0.3.0

Here are some things I've tried so far:

Reinstalled Miniconda and VS Code
Cleared all cache from pip and conda base
Installed the package with the --no-cache-dir flag
Tried multiple Python versions (from 3.10.x to 3.11.x)

The expected results are to be able to use:
RetrievalQA
create_retrieval_chain

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

make sure you are using the same pip and python version by pip -V to see if the python version is the one you're using within the vscode as the selected interpreter or desired virtual env ...

Hi, thanks for the suggestion, i just checked and i use pip 24.2 (i think is the latest) and python 3.10 (which matches my versions)

i used dir() to see what is inside langchain.chainsand this is what i have: ( ['Any', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__getattr__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '_module_lookup', 'create_importer', 'importer']) . So i am definitely missing a lot of methods

Try from langchain.chains.retrieval_qa.base import RetrievalQA; from langchain.chains.retrieval import create_retrieval_chain.

@cottontail it absolutely works! Thansk so much, where did you find this out? In the docs is not mentioned
